# Visual Studio Browser Link Causes InvalidOperationException: Stack empty

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, custom-server-controls, browser-link

I have a version 4.6 WebForms web site and a simple, custom WebControl. When I do something like:

```
[PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
public SomeControl Contents { get; set; }

public override void RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) {
    // Simplified code
    Contents.RenderControl(writer);
}
```

... I can insert the control exactly once i a page and all is fine. If however I insert the control more than once, or if I add another property like `Contents` in the example above and then run `RenderControl` on both controls in the local override (i.e. in the body of `public override void RenderControl`), I get an exception:

> [InvalidOperationException: Stack empty.]
>      System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource) +52
>   System.Collections.Generic.Stack`1.Pop() +6856361
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime.WebForms.SelectionMappingRenderTraceListener.EndRendering(TextWriter writer, Object renderedObject) +84
>   System.Web.UI.RenderTraceListenerList.EndRendering(TextWriter writer, Object renderedObject) +66
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +170
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +9796138
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1303

Apparently, this error is caused by the Visual Studio Browser Link feature (or its subsequent functions). If I disable it the error goes away.

This same problem has been discussed in other contexts like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33177942/c-sharp-error-invalidoperationexception-stack-empty), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23892882/invalidoperationexception-stack-empty) and also [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34954077/invalidoperationexception-stack-empty-when-open-sitefinity-project-in-visual) to point out but a few examples, and several fixes have been suggested. The fixes though are all related to completely or partially disable the Browser Link or Page Inspector features.

I would like to know if anyone has a solution to prevent the error from occuring by altering the code within the `public override void RenderControl` method of my code example, introducing some checking of something or whatever?